# Mux for ultra low noise pre-amplifier

Tags: noise, multiplexer

I am searching for a method for multiplexing 3 DC voltage sources (each ±10V p-p) to my ADC pre-amplifier circuit.

My requirement is that the multiplexer should not inject excessive noise into the readings. It should be as noise free as possible, like 1 µV peak to peak max.

I'm considering building my multiplexer with switches or relays. For switch [ADG1401](http://www.analog.com/en/switchesmultiplexers/analog-switches/adg1401/products/product.html) looks promising (however, in the data sheet I couldn't find noise related data)

Can a relay be more noise free? Do you have advice about other solutions for this requirement?

Comment: Have you actually thought about this?  1uV/20V is 1 part in 20M.  Unless you have a 24 bit A/D this level of signal to noise ratio is pointless.  Forget the mux, what about the preamp?  Is it really good to 150dB signal to noise ratio?  There are many many other things you need to consider with that kind of S/N and resolution.  Anyone that actually knows what they are doing in that regime wouldn't be asking here about the mux, so I'm thinking you need to go back and re-evaluate what you really have and what the requirements really are.  What exactly are you trying to measure?

Comment: Why do you need a preamplifier with such large signals.  Eliminating the preamplifier will reduce potential noise.

Comment: @Barry, I guess I need to give more details to make the question clear. I need 1uV error margin when the input signal is in 1mV range. I plan to use mux inputs 2,3 for precision reference voltages for continues calibration of the 1. input. This will hopefully solve the offset errors in amplifier circuits. In this question I want to get answers for the best solution for a mux which will add minimum noise to the inputs. Aspecially is a regular relay less noisy than a switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relay is your right choice unfortunately (because they wear out and are noisy).  I know for a fact that systems that use SQUID magnetometers use relays simply because of low electrical noise.  We used reed relays for the low parasitics and good signal flow.

Comment: Ordinary mechanical contacts can be noisy if there is vibration.  For such a very low noise requirement as this, I would want mercury-wetted relays.

Comment: Thanks, good point, I forgot that indeed that is what is used.

Answer (score 4):

I think your noise requirement is unrealistic. Do you really have a preamplifier and ADC that gives you more than 24 noise-free bits?

You mention DC signals; what is the noise bandwidth that you care about?

Let's look at the datasheet for the part you mention. There's actually lots of noise-related information there; you're just not seeing it.

The on resistance of the ADG1401 is on the order of 1 Ω. This means that you can pass no more than 1 µA through it before you create a 1 LSB offset in the measurement.

Leakage currents are on the order of 3 nA (typical over temperature). This means that your input impedance can be no more than 330 Ω without creating a 1 LSB offset in a measurement.

Isolation is shown as being on the order of -100 dB at frequencies less than about 10 kHz. This means that 100 µV of your 10-V signal can leak through to your preamp, perturbing the measurements of the other input channels.

THD+noise is given as 0.008% at frequencies as low as 20 Hz. This is an error of 800 µV on a 10-V signal.

Finally, the ACPSRR is shown as being -90 dB at best. This means that you need to keep the noise on the power rails to less than 31 mV in order to inject less than 1 µV of noise into the measurement.

Comment: Hi the noise level of 1uV should be satisfied when the input is in 1 mv range. How about the relay solution. Do you think it is more suitable for this?

Comment: I guess the most critical one is the leakage current for 1 mv range measurement. I have source impedance of 10KOhm. 10K x 3nA = 30uV